# wp get_calendar to link up next/prev month calendar?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to find a way to alter the default WP Calendar so when I click on the "Next" and "Prev" buttons it actually loads another calendar month as opposed to linking to the list of posts.

As someone who is only learning php do you think this is a big undertaking and Im wondering could someone give me a description (not code exactly) as to what I should do.
Ive been altering the

I have already altered the calendar enough at this stage for other functionality that I can't just download a plugin to do everything, (also Im struggling to find a plugin that does everything I need).

Ive been altering the `get_calendar` function in general-templates.php

Apologies for the vague question, I think if I had a basic understanding of what I should do I could write the code myself.

Comment: what is `default` calendar? there is NO any calendar plugins in wordpress by default.

Comment: sorry what I meant the default function that creates a calender, that can be used in a sidebar or as a widget etc.

Comment: after thinking about it, I think I have an answer , create another function thats the same as the original one, upon clicking on the link , load that function up but instead the current month being +1.

Probably simply for some, but will have to learn a bit.

Comment: [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1133) is `$prev` and `$next` post. And some lines down - generating next and prev links. Look it through. Only you can help yourself for now. We haven't code and dont see whole scene.